# non continuous partial derivatives and differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> If $f_x, f_y$ are **not** continuous at $(x_1, y_1) = (a, b)$ then is $f$ **not** differentiable  at $(a, b)$?

In general case, is this true?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, this is false even in dimension $1$. For example $x\mapsto x^2\sin(1/x)$ and $0$ at $0$.